# Client server over wireless network

Tags: network-programming, visual-studio-2012, client-server, ip

Is it possible to set up a simple client server application to send text and other data over a wireless network in a LAN situation between two computers without setting up any network shares? By just knowing the IP address?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. WiFi is just like any other network, you use TCP/IP over it to implement any network protocol you like.